# Size is always zero when reading DRM EDID file

Tags: c++, linux

I tried to read the EDID of my monitor connected to LVDS1. I use ArchLinux and C++/clang. My problem is: the file size always returns 0. I don't know if this is a programming problem or something OS specific, other files return a proper file size. Is it a special file? Is the symlink directory `/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1` the problem?

#### file: `/sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid`

#### code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

long
get_file_size(FILE *f)
{
    long pos_cursor, pos_end;
    pos_cursor = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, 2);
    pos_end = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, pos_cursor, 0);
    return pos_end;
}

int
main()
{
    const char *filepath = "/sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid";
    FILE *file = NULL;

    if((file = fopen(filepath, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "file could not be opened" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "file opened" << endl;

    long filesize = get_file_size(file);
    cout << "file size: " << filesize << endl;

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

#### output:

```
file opened
file size: 0
```

===

as suggested by MSalters, I tried stat for the file size. Also returns 0. I assume the code is correct, so it is somehow just not possible to access the file?

I also tried the symlink target path (`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/edid`), just in case that was the problem - but still 0.

#### code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    const char *filepath = "/sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid";
    struct stat results;
    
    if (stat(filepath, &results) == 0)
        cout << results.st_size << endl;
    else
        cout << "error" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### output

```
0
```

===

I tried other files in the same directory (`dpms  edid  enabled  i2c-6  modes  power  status  subsystem  uevent`). They all return a filesize of 4096 except `edid`.

Comment: Not a lot of C++ code, the file stuff is all C code.

Comment: @MSalters Oh, but it "is" C++: `using namespace std;`

Comment: you are right, I just googled and copied the code from here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/170054-understanding-and-reading-binary-files-in-c/

Comment: I wonder if it is a permission issue. Does it work any different if running as root? With a command like `cat` (or `xxd`), does that list the contents under the same account?

Comment: cat works, it returns the binary as ascii chars though

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `fseek(f, 0, 2);` might mean `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR);` which obviously doesn't do anything. You'd want `SEEK_END` which isn't portable, but then again `/sys/` isn't either. (Of course, do `#include <stdio.h>`)

But considering it's already Linux-specific, why not use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) ?